# Unable to download CSV file using python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, stock

I am using the following code to get a csv file from the link "https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-pit?index=equities&from_date=24-09-2023&to_date=24-12-2023&csv=true"

Note that "from_date=24-09-2023&to_date=24-12-2023"  are dates. The difference between these two dates should be 4 months.

The downloaded csv file should then be renamed as "Insider.CSV"

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time

def download_csv_with_selenium():
    # Set up ChromeOptions to download files to a specific directory and include headers
    chrome_options = Options()
    download_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("Insider.csv"))
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": download_directory})
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36")
    chrome_options.add_argument("accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9")
    chrome_options.add_argument("accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br")
    chrome_options.add_argument("referer=https://www.nseindia.com/")

    # Initialize the WebDriver with Chrome and set options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    try:
        # Open the URL
        driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-insider-trading")

        # Scroll down 300 pixels (adjust as needed)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300);")

        # Find and click the button with text "3M"
        button_3m = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='3M']"))
        )
        button_3m.click()

        # Wait for 10 seconds
        time.sleep(10)

        # Find and click the button with text "Download(.csv)"
        button_download = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Download(.csv)']"))
        )
        button_download.click()

        # Wait for the download to complete (adjust this based on the expected download time)
        time.sleep(10)

        # Rename the downloaded file
        downloaded_file_path = os.path.join(download_directory, "DownloadedFile.csv")
        os.rename(downloaded_file_path, "Insider.csv")
        print("File downloaded and renamed successfully: Insider.csv")

    finally:
        # Close the browser window
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Download the CSV file with Selenium
    download_csv_with_selenium()
```

However when I run the script I am getting the following error on the webpage

The web page at https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-pit?index=equities&from_date=25-09-2023&to_date=25-12-2023&csv=true might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I dont know how to resolve this

Comment: The URL doesn't work interactively either, make sure you're fetching it from the right address.

Comment: The difference between 24-09-2023 and 24-12-2023 is 3 months, not 4.